# Angular 6: pass id from one component to another component

Tags: angular

### My situation:

I have a Login Component ,when i will login , i will get response from API like

```
{
  code: 200,
  id: 4,
  msg: "success",
  user: "Sourav"
}
```

I want to send this id to Candidate component ,cv Details Component  and Key skills component .

### My code

MyCommonService:

```
import{ Injectable } from'@angular/core';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CommonUserService {
  public userId;

  constructor() {}

  setUserLoggedIn(Id) {
    this.userId = Id;
    console.log(this.userId);
  }

  getUserLoggedIn() {
    console.log(this.userId);
    return this.userId;
  }

}
```

### LoginComponent

Here I am setting the id using common service

```
login() {
  if (this.seekerlogin.code == '200') {
    this.commonuserservice.setUserLoggedIn(this.seekerlogin.id);
  }
}
```

### Candiadate Component

Here it's showing id is Undefined

```
 submit(){
 let id = this.commonuserservice.getUserLoggedIn(); // Here showing id is  
 Undefined
 let name = this.name;
 this.companydetailssevice.candidateServiceMethod(id,name)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
        this.ResponseVariable= data;
           if(this.ResponseVariable.code =='200'){ 
            this.router.navigate(['key_skill']);                   
             }
    },
    error => alert(error),
    () => console.log(this.ResponseVariable)
  );
}
```

please help me where i am doing wrong or tell me any other solutions

Comment: Welcome. Do you need to retrieve the value on the same page/request as you stored it, or on future ones as well? Also, do you work with a server (which you make HTTP requests to), or you just have an Angular client? If you don't work with a server and you need to store the login info for future requests, take a look at [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)).

Comment: For all component interactions, this page of the docs is excellent - https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: ya using localStorageage i can do this but is it secure ?@Jeto

Comment: Your code looks good, but please put this code in js fiddel or Stcakblitz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We have multiple ways to share data from one controller to another.
>   But in simple way you can go with localStorage.

Please check sample code.

**Step 1:** Alter your service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonUserService {
    constructor() { }
    //State Management
    setSession(key: string, value: any): void {
        //sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
    getSession(key: string): any {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            //let retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem(key) as string;
            let retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem(key) as string;
            return retrievedObject;
        }
    }
    clearSession(): void {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Set and Get session value.

```
 this._commonUserService.setSession('UserId', UserId);
 let userId= this._commonUserService.getSession('UserId');
```

Comment: If it's not needed to save the value for the usage of other tabs use `sessionStorage` for one tab only.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. What you're doing is the correct way to go. Just make sure you're running a single instance of `CommonUserService` in all the components. Make sure you have added `CommonUserService` to the `providers` array in a module and not in individual components.

```js
import{ Injectable } from'@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonUserService {
  public userId;

  constructor() {}

  setUserLoggedIn(Id) {
    this.userId = Id;
    console.log(this.userId);
  }

  getUserLoggedIn() {
    console.log(this.userId);
    return this.userId;
  }

}
```

Then in your module

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ItemDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    
  ],
  providers: [CommonUserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And your compoenents

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bank-account',
  template: `
    Bank Name: {{ bankName }}
    Account Id: {{ id }}
  `
})
export class BankAccountComponent {
  bankName: string|null = null;
  id: string|null = null;
 
 constructor(private commonService: CommonUserService){
 }
 }
```

Comment: please check i have  edited my code but still it's showing id is Undefined.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is. Can you post your code on Stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)? I'll take a look.